# How to make angular project as a library and use it in JS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Can we make an angular library and use it in a JS project like the below shown image.

> In this project structure trading-vue.min.js is an angular library. Is it possible or i have to do it some other way?

[image]

Comment: At the end everything is javascript, let's assume you are using Visual Studio with the regular Asp.Net core + Angular template, if you publish your project you will notice that your typescript code will be transpilled into a pure javascript code. What you need to do is just put everything in a single .min.js file (which I don't recommend).

Comment: yes, i have a project and the client demanding this structure of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are possibillities to achieve framework agnostic components by using Angular Elements and uploading that for example to a private npm registry/proxy like [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio). (Or even NPM)

Angular has extensive documentation on creating so called Custom elements with Angular Elements. Custom elements is a standard, supported by a large amount of browsers, that seeks to create HTML components in a framework agnostic way. Here you can find the official docs for the angular approach [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

There are quite good videos on youtube by Manfred Steyer from the `ng-conf`, where he is somewhat deep diving into it --> [A Deep Look At Angular Elements | Manfred Steyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QU0mpyF7bQ) and [Web Components with Angular Elements: Beyond the Basics | Manfred Steyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9i3YBFxSSE)

Also you might find this articles helpful --> [Angular Elements: A Guide to Shipping Framework-Agnostic Libraries](https://medium.com/vendasta/angular-elements-a-guide-to-shipping-framework-agnostic-libraries-13b02b2b284f) or [Peacefully United thanks to Micro Apps and Web Components](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/angular-react-vue-js-and-co/)

`My personal` opinion/experience was, that it felt a bit hacky to achieve this framework agnostic inter communication and whole wiring up of different "Web Components", also your project structure might get overall more complex, but it might be, that time will change that.